# Clear recent created file names in WinSCP

Tags: cache, winscp, recentx

I would like to know how to clear recent created file names that appearing in the dialogue box when creating a new file:

[image: recent file names]

I tried a lot without success

Answer (score 1):

While in the drop down list, press <kbd>Ctrl+Del</kbd>.

To commit that, you need to submit the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I clear recent created file names?

- When you right-click the entry, there's a "Remove from this list" command, or
- Remove the `JumpList` value from the `HKCU\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\Configuration` registry key.

Source: [Recently Sites List :: Support Forum :: WinSCP](https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=26938)

Comment: That's a different list than the one OP refers to.

Answer (score 0):

Not working, but I searched accross the other keys and was able to find the values for he file names inside the following key and delete them:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\Configuration\History\EditFile

Thank you for your help.