# Clear find history in WinSCP

Tags: ssh, winscp

I would like to clear find history in WinSCP as shown in the following picture:

[image: WinSCP find history]

Hope you can help in this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use `regedit` to navigate to the key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\Configuration\History`.

Export the key for backup, then delete it.

Comment: I've already deleted it but the history still shown

Comment: That's the advice given by Martin Prikryl, the author of WinSCO. If it's not enough, better ask him on the WinSCP forums (or here).

Comment: This also works. But make sure you close WinSCP before doing it. Anyway, see [Clear recent created file names in WinSCP](https://superuser.com/q/1616455/213663).